# Ninject property injection in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, ninject, ninject.web

My code is as fallows below. My issue is the Session is not injected and my session remains Null. What is wrong here? I am using ninject 2.2

```
    public class SessionNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession());
        this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(NHRepository<>)).InRequestScope(); 

    }
}

    public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
    public MvcApplication()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
        this.EndRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_EndRequest);
    }

    void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory).Dispose();
    }

    void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=VARTAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mdlivenh;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)).ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread_static"))
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                // Include both standard NHibernate mapping files and Fluent NHibernate mapping files
                //m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<User>();
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHMDLive.Models.Mappings.StudyMap>();
            }).BuildSessionFactory();

    }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the controllerfactory (I think)
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
    public class NHRepository<T> : IQueryable<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity
{
    private ISession _session;

    [Inject]
    public ISession session
    {
        get { return _session; }
        set { _session = value; }
    }

    #region IRepository Members

    virtual public T Get(object id)
    {
        return TryCatch(() => session.Get<T>(id));
    }}
```

Usage: NHRepository repository = new NHRepository();

Comment: Do you have a controller factory set up?

Comment: @Daniel any examples that you think will solve the issue?

Comment: @Daniel OnApplicationStarted is supposed to create the controller factory

Comment: What does it look like in the `base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine. How are you instantiating your NHRepository? Be sure to let Ninject create it for you, otherwise it won't have a chance to set the session property.

Example:

```
// Tell Ninject to give us an NHRepository.
var repository = ninjectKernel.Get<NHRepository<Foo>>();
```

---

Alternately, instead of using the [Ninject] attribute, the NHRepository itself could grab it's session from the kernel:

```
public ISession Session
{
    get { return ninjectKernel.Get<ISession>(); }
}
```

Comment: i cannot find a ninjectKernel.Get, what library or how do i declare that?

Comment: ninjectKernel is just the kernel you created in the CreateKernel method. Store that kernel somewhere, then call .Get on it.

Comment: Do I need to create a servicelocator

Comment: I haven't had to, no. I may be mistaken, but I believe that is something new to MVC 3.

Comment: Did this question solve your problem? I notice you haven't upvoted any repsponses, nor marked any responses as the answer.